# How to fix infinite redirect loop?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm running my own MVC structure and I've ran into an issue that I can't figure out how to get around or fix. I've looked at various other questions like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258712/php-redirect-loop), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889324/infinite-loop-on-login-redirect), and many others which didn't quite help.

I have a table in the database that returns a user's information, if the information isn't found then redirect them to a page to force them to submit the data.

I created a Authenticated class which extends the controller (contains the redirect method):

```
abstract class Authenticated extends \Core\Controller {

    protected function before() {
        $this->requirePersonality();
    }

    protected function requirePersonality(){
        if(!(new PlannerAuth())->getPersonality()){
            $this->redirect('/app/personalization');
        }
    }
}
```

In my App Controller I've got:

```
class App extends Authenticated {

    protected function before(){
        parent::before();
    }

    public function personalizationAction(){
        View::renderTemplate('App/personalization.html');
    }
}
```

The before() method will run before any and every action method, so when I run any url in the application the following logic happens:

Authentication `before()` runs, redirects me to **/app/personalization**, once there, it checks the current `before()`, which reruns the authentication `before()` method again, and on and on.. creating an infinite loop.

I've also got an `after()` method, which will run after all of the methods, but that won't work since it won't force the user onto the personalization page.

This will only happen when I run any method in the App controller, I could have the `personalizationAction` in another controller, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a `parent::before();` calling in the before function of your /app/personalization controller. You can have an implementation of `requirePersonality()` inside that class but avoiding the redirection to the same controller.

Comment: Per your answer, how would I run the function from the authentication then? Let's say I have a requireLogin() function, if the user isn't logged in, redirects them to the login page? Using this(requireLogin) as an example based on my issue, it'd work since the login would have it's own controller, hence redirection would work.

Comment: Exactly. If the session time is over or the user is not logged in, this should be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Alright, which leaves me to fix the problem with the personalization page now. Maybe I'll just create another controller for it, it'd be nice if I could manage what I was trying to do, redirect to the same controller, but I'll manage I guess, thank you.

Comment: I still have a problem though, I need to redirect to any controller, that's fine but the requirePersonality method is inside the Authentication Class which is extended to all of the app controllers, so I'm lost.. I'm back to the problem.

Comment: The Autenticated class has just two functions: before and requirePersonality. You won't call parent::before in the login controller, so you just have to redefine requirePersonality again there. Don't make Login controller to extend Autenticated class, but to extend Core/Controller class.